# user says keyboard won't hide, cannot replicate results

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a textfield and, after the user has entered their name, the use can either press enter, or press a custom Done button. Both of these works correctly on my devices in hiding the keyboard. However, a user is reporting that the keyboard is not hiding, and he/she has to force quit the app to get rid of it. As i am unable to replicate this error, I don't know what could possibly be causing it.

I bring up the keyboard like this, when the dialog box shows up:
[textInputName becomeFirstResponder];

and hide it like this:
[textInputName resignFirstResponder];

There is absolutely no way that the user can avoid resignfirstresponder as I see it.

Please tell me if you need any more info.

EDIT: here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/tLbP4u9x

Comment: Where u write this line [textInputName becomeFirstResponder]; in ur code?

Comment: There is a button which calls it, along with code that sets the textInputname.hidden to false.

Comment: TextField automatically shows key board, why r u bring up manually?

Comment: I bring it up manually so the user doesn't have to tap the textfield.

Comment: u don't need to call key board manually,u have possible to post ur code?

Comment: Well, without that code, the user has to tap the textfield. I want the keyboard to show up when the user taps the button.Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/a5QKbkMZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `textInputName.text.length > 3` condition isn't met, `retainKeyboard` won't be set to `false` and the keyboard will remain visible.

Comment: Thank you so much:) That made me look and I realized there were an old method assigned to the button which should resign the keyboard, which did something completely different. It is still odd that I have never enouctered this bug myself, but now I think it is resolved. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This method can return before resigning text field

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    return !retainKeyboard;
  [textInputName resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And you set text user name to TextField I think you don't need show editing mode to user. Hope this will help you.

Comment: You are correct of course. However, the "[textInputName resignFirstResponder];" was something  was something I added just now, and I should have taken that out. It is not the issue as the version in the app store does not have that code.